# I do not understand 'this' being used with a superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I have two classes and an interface shown below. 
Quick summary: Interface Winterface, Class Big, Class Little that extends Big and implements Winterface.

```
public interface Winterface {}


public class Big {

    public int hello = 88;

    public Big() {}

    public void theMethod() {
        System.out.println ("Big was here: " + (this instanceof Winterface) + ", " + this.hello);
    }
}

public class Little extends Big implements Winterface{

    private boolean hello = true;
    public Little(){}

    public void theMethod() {
        super.theMethod();
        System.out.println("Little was here: " + hello);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Little l = new Little();
        l.theMethod();
    }
}
```

When I execute the main in Little, I get the following output

Big was here: true, 88
Little was here: true

my question is, how can

1) (this instanceof Winterface) return true but

2) this.hello be 88?
If this.hello = 88, then this = Big, which isn't an instance of Winterface.

I do not understand how this is possible, thanks in advance

EDIT: THANKS everyone I understand now that 'this' refers to little, which is a Big and implements Winterface. Since the method is being called as super.theMethod(), the variable 'hello' available is the one in Big even though 'this' refers to little.

Comment: Relevant reading @ http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-these-java-inheritance-gotchas/5031837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` can only be one class.  However `this.hello` is the field accessible to that class.

As `this` can only be one class it is a `Little` which has a parent `Big` and implements `Winterface` When you call a method in its parent which can only see `hello` that is what it sees.

i.e. Java supports polymorphism for methods but not fields.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about `Winterface` though.

Comment: Java supports polymorphism for methods but not fields.
THANKS, this basically cleared it up

Answer (score 2):

`l` is `Little` but `Little` is a `Big` **and** also implements the behavior of `Winterface`.
The `super` is a call to the parent class so the `hello` member of the parent class (i.e. `Big`) is used.
You are not doing `this.hello` but `super.theMethod()` that uses the **parent's** class member variable `hello`.

**UPDATE:**
The `super.theMethod()` invokes the corresponding method in the parent class. In the parent class you access the fields of the parent (which also belong to the derived class since `Little` is also a `Big`). So the `this.hello` at that point is accessing the part of the code that is of the parent class.
You can imagine the memory print of `Little` as follows:

```
++++++++
+ Big  +
--------
+Little+
++++++++
```

So `Little` has all the members variables of the parent i.e. `Big` and when the code runs inside `super.theMethod()` it is running inside the "code area" of `Big`.
As Peter states in his answer, polymorhism is not supported for methods and I hope that this overly simplistic description helps understand this

Comment: huh? I am doing this.hello in the super.theMethod(). How can the 'this' be referencing two separate things in the same method?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `this instanceof ...` check does not use the static (i.e., compile-time) type (which is `Big`), but the object's (`this`') dynamic run-time type (i.e., `this.getClass()`), which is `Little` in your example. If it would use the static type, the operator would be pretty pointless, since we would have:

```
Object obj = "foo";

if (obj instanceof Object) { /* always entered */ }
/* but */ if (obj instanceof String) { /* never entered */ }
```

statically, at compile-time. The purpose of the `instanceof` operator is to enable run-time type testing, for example:

```
Object obj = /* whatever */;

if (obj instanceof String) {

    String str = (String)obj;   // Cast cannot fail
    ...

} else if (obj instanceof Long) {

    Long val = (Long)obj;       // Cast cannot fail
    ...
}
```

Note, that this technique should only be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is an instance of Big and of Little. It's a direct instance of Little, but since Little inherits from Big the instanceof operator will return true for Big too.

```
Little l = new Little();
System.out.println(l instanceof Little); // true, l is an instance Little
System.out.println(l instanceof Big); // true, l is an instance of Little which inherits from Big
```

Your other misunderstanding (I'm assuming) is how the 'method lookup' works. When you call theMethod the it picks Little's implementation of that method. When you call super.theMethod though, you've explicitly said "call Big's version of this method", and then inside that method it's using Big's hello variable rather than Little's hello variable.

Comment: I understand, but IN that method, the 'this' seemed to refer both little and big to me. I understand now that this is a little and a big and implements winterface

Comment: The type of 'this' depends on where you call 'this'. The object itself is of course a Little, however the code that's running at that point is in Big. Thus, 'this' is assumed at that point to be a Big because you're running Big's code. Big has no built-in knowledge of Little, so can't treat 'this' as a Little.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that when you are defining your variable `hello` in `Little` you are not overwriting the variable `hello` that is inside `Big` you are defining a new variable `hello` within `Little` that is hiding the variable `hello` within `Big`. Thus within the scope of `Big`, `hello` will refer to the integer value of 88 and within the scope of `Little`, `hello` will refer to true. These are different variables both contained within your object, the only difference is the scope by which you refer to them.

Like others here have said, `instanceof` is an operator that compares the runtime type of your object (what is returned by `this.getClass()`). When in `Big` even though the scope of the variables within your object will refer to `Big`, `this` is still of runtime type `Little` which is why it is an instance of `Winterface`.